# Azure Python Function datetime expression

Tags: python, azure, datetime, azure-functions

May I know the difference between `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` and `datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`?

The second one is from the [Azure Function doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python#example), it was already specify with UTC time via `.utcnow()`, is it necessary to add `.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)` to specify the UTC time again? Per my test, they output the same time.

Comment: `utcnow` might sound like it returns UTC but in fact only returns datetime that *looks like* current UTC. The datetime object has no tzinfo attached, thus is naive, thus will be treated as *local time* by Python. See also: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html

Comment: IMHO, if you want to write this concisely, use `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)`.

Comment: @FObersteiner Thanks for your reply. So you mean `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` actually outputs the local time? And may I know if `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)` you mentioned outputs the same result as `datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`?

Comment: "*datetime.datetime.utcnow() actually outputs the local time?*" to be precise: no. It gives you a datetime object with attributes set to current UTC date/time. But the object is naive, meaning it is not specified to be UTC. Without that specification, Python will treat is as local time. That's just confusing and I'd therefore avoid utcnow in most contexts. Regarding your second question, yes, the output of those two expressions is the same. I just think the first one is more clear ;-)

Comment: @FObersteiner Thanks for the detailed explanation, if you can post it as an answer, I'm glad to accept it.

Comment: I tried to make it more specific to the Azure docs. I think their expresion `utc_timestamp = ...` is a bit convoluted ^^ `utcnow` (and related `utcfromtimestamp`) is kind of a pain in the Python world. Also, `.isoformat` has a correctness-problem imho (+00:00 offset is not necessarily UTC... should use Z instead), but that might be nit-picking ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the object representation of what you get from the two expressions:

```py
import datetime

dt1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
dt2 = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

print(repr(dt1))
# datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 18, 7, 33, 42, 993707)

print(repr(dt2))
# datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 18, 7, 33, 42, 993707, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

The first expressions gives you a datetime object with attributes set to current UTC date/time. But [the object is naive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects), meaning it is not specified to be UTC, the `tzinfo` is not set. The second expressions changes that, by replacing the tzinfo to be UTC. That has consequences for `.isoformat` output (it's used in the Azure docs):

```py
print(dt1.isoformat())
# 2022-05-18T07:33:42.993707

print(dt2.isoformat())
# 2022-05-18T07:33:42.993707+00:00
```

The second expressions has a UTC offset attached, the first one hasn't.

#### Why care?

Python will treat **naive datetime** as **local time**. That can be pretty confusing if you expect UTC because you used `utcnow`... Setting the tzinfo right away is the better option in most contexts. A concise expression giving you the same result whilst avoiding utcnow would be

```py
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
```